# variable scope in the context of a match pattern

Tags: variables, rust, scope, match

I have a file in which each line is of the form :

```
    key$password (key + separator + password)
```

so that I can do

```
    let (key , password) = line.split_once("$").unwrap() ;** // to get key and password
```

the first line is special (id, secret_key) and I need this secret key to decode the passwords
in a function where I have declared :

```
    let mount count = 0;
    let user_password = String::new();**
```

Then I run a loop

```
    for line in reader.lines() {
       count += 1;
       match line {
          match count {
             1 => {  here I split_once and  get a value of user_password )
             _ => now I want to parse the following lines using user_password obtained from the 1 arm of the match 
              ... etc
           }
```

my problem is that although user_password is valid in arm 1 (or an if then clause), but is not set in the context of arm 2
There is something that I cannot understand : I declare usr_password in the whole context of the function, in the match arm 1 I set the variable to a value ,but when I am in arm 2 (that is for line 2 .. end this variable is not set

any help would be terribly appreciated (I'm a beginner, sorry)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: If the first line is special, then handle it specially first... before you loop over the rest of the lines...

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn logic(file_contents: &str) {
    // this is an iterator, it has its own state and you can call
    // .next to get one line
    let mut lines = file_contents.lines();

    // so called `let-else` statement, if `lines.next()` if `None`
    // the else block is executed
    let Some(header) = lines.next() else {
        // `todo!` will terminate your program if reached
        // the advantage is that compiler is happy and you
        // can debug happy path
        todo!("handle missing header"); 
    };

    // same as above
    let Some((key, password)) = header.split_once("$") else {
        todo!("handle invalid header")
    };

    // now that we taken first line and processed it, you can consume
    // the remaining lines by a loop
    for line in lines {
        // its always good to separate the concerns of your program
        let Some(res) = decode(line, key, password) else {
            continue; // or handle the error
        };

        // use `res`
    }
}

// TODO: choose appropriate return type, `()` is placeholder for now
// `Option<T>` signifies function can fail and return nothing
fn decode(line: &str, key: &str, password: &str) -> Option<()> {
    todo!("implement decode");
}
```

Comment: So when I loop using and iterator such as :

Comment: Does that means that the scope of a variable set inside a loop in an iterator is closed  to the iterator ? so that you cannot set a variable defined in the surrounding scope (e.g a function). If so could you provide a link to the documentation ?

Comment: Rust cannot prove that branch `1` in fact executed first. You either have to use option or give your type a default value before the loop so it is always initialized.